# Karma Jasmine AngularJS module not defined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This question seems to have been asked a lot but none of the answers solve my issue.

I am trying to run a karma-jasmine test that looks like (following is the mySpec.js file)

```
    describe('Testing', function () {

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('firsttest', function () {

    it('should set the value of First Name', function () {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.vm.FirstName = "John Smit";
    }); 


  });

});
```

And in the karma.conf.js file my files section is as follows

```
files: [
  'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
  'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.min.js',
  'node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js',
  'js/dist/allapp.js',
  'js/tests/mySpec.js'
],
```

no matter what i do, which included creating a pure jasmine test in a seperate html file or change the files[] i always get the same error

```
encountered a declaration exception FAILED
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try `angular.mock.module`

Comment: The response i get is `angular.mock.module is not a function`

Comment: Oh my angular-mocks.min.js is supposed to be without min thanks for making me take a closer look at it

Comment: The module error is gone but now i got another error. As it can not .getContext of a canvase on my html.

Comment: Ok it's an other problem, not about testing. :) I posted an answer with my first comment, if you want to accept it to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `angular.mock.module()` instead of `module()`